# How to setup an variable ENV inside Dockerfile to be overriden in a Docker container?

Tags: variables, docker, environment

I have a container that should be created with the IP user.

This is what i have inside the Dockerfile:

```
ENV REMOTE_HOST=xxxxxxxxxx

RUN { \
        echo '[xdebug]'; \
        echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000'; \  
        echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'; \
        echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug'; \
        echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_host=$REMOTE_HOST'; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

And this is how I create an container derived from that Dockerfile:
dockerrun an image from that Dockerfile:

```
docker run -e REMOTE_HOST=123456   -p 80:80  -v /Users/myusrname/Documents/mysite:/var/www/html myImage
```

This is what I have in php.ini inside the container:

```
root@1713e0a338f9:/var/www/html# cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
...
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=$REMOTE_HOST
```

What is the correct way to pass that variable?

Comment: As `php.ini` supports environment variables this should work, did you verify the var is set in the container, i.e. `echo $REMOTE_HOST`? Maybe curly braces are required in the ini file, i.e. `"${REMOTE_HOST}"`.

Comment: Hey Erik, for sure is something related with curly braces. I am trying to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to pass in data that will be *built with the image* then you're looking for `ARG` and `--build-arg`; which can be found in the [Dockerfile documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG REMOTE_HOST

RUN echo ${REMOTE_HOST} > /my_file
```

**Then build the file:**

```
➜  docker build -t test_image --build-arg REMOTE_HOST=1.2.3.4 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.24kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 20c44cd7596f
Step 2/3 : ARG REMOTE_HOST
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9815e560847
Step 3/3 : RUN echo ${REMOTE_HOST} > /my_file
 ---> Running in da07d5d060b7
 ---> cdfdbeac71b9
```

**Run the image and print out the file:**

```
➜  docker run test_image cat /my_file
1.2.3.4
```

I'll leave this with a note though; that you probably don't want to be hard-coding an IP address to your image; and instead you should set up your image to instead read the environment variable and update that file at runtime; in that case, once your Dockerfile is setup to handle that - you would use `docker run -e REMOTE_HOST=1.2.3.4`. Do this, you'll want something like:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh # Or ensure it's +x already

ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**php.ini**

```
{
    echo '[xdebug]';
    echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp';
    echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug';
    echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_host=$REMOTE_HOST';
}
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Check if our environment variable has been passed.
if [ -z "${REMOTE_HOST}" ]
then
  echo "REMOTE_HOST has not been set."
  exit 1
else
  sed -i.bak "s/\$REMOTE_HOST/${REMOTE_HOST}/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
fi

exec "$@"
```

**Build the image:**

```
➜  docker build -t test_image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 20c44cd7596f
Step 2/5 : COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
 ---> 1785c0238ce8
Step 3/5 : COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
 ---> c63c289c411e
Step 4/5 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh # Or ensure it's +x already
 ---> Running in 09b07f8724a9
 ---> 66ab090f405a
Removing intermediate container 09b07f8724a9
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 1f5a7ebec98e
 ---> 2992128843cd
Removing intermediate container 1f5a7ebec98e
Successfully built 2992128843cd
Successfully tagged test_image:lates
```

**Run the image and provide REMOTE_HOST**

```
➜  docker run -e REMOTE_HOST=1.2.3.4 test_image cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
{
    echo '[xdebug]';
    echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp';
    echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug';
    echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0';
    echo 'xdebug.remote_host=1.2.3.4';
}
```

Comment: Hi TJ, in fact I have a bash script that runs the code to create the container.  I grab the ip like that REMOTE_HOST=`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'` and then I should pass it to the run command.

Comment: Are you attempting to **build** the container with the IP; or do you want it to be dynamic upon running the container? Your question was phrased as building it with the IP; so the answer above will solve that.

Comment: Im trying to pass the Ip upon running the container. Your approach worked for the "building" image process. But it do not override upon run.

Comment: @zwitterion Updated my answer to pass it in on runtime.

Comment: Hi TJ, I am new in Docker. Your solution, it works, but now I can't use the container, because when I run the docker command,  it creates the container and closes it. So how can I solve this? My question, as a Docker beginner is - is it the only way to achieve the goal? Is it possible to solve it using ENV or ARG?

Comment: @zwitterion Please post your full `Dockerfile`

Comment: ok... I found a way... just call like this `docker run -e REMOTE_HOST=1.2.3.4 test_image apache2-foreground` Now it works 100%. It is not with ENV or ARG but works. Thanks

Comment: Hi TJ, quick question, This container holds a apache/php service and Redis as well. What I do is I run `docker run -e REMOTE_HOST=1.2.3.4 test_image apache2-foreground` and the container is started. After that I must to open a new window and get access to the container trough `docker -it exec containerId bash` and then run `redis-server`. At this point I will have 2 opened terminals. How and where could I start redis server during the time the container is created in order to avoid this extra step?

Comment: @zwitterion - Look into Docker Compose; you'll be able to define your Redis and Apache container in one file. If you're not already; Redis and Apache should be two entirely different containers - don't run Redis in your Apache container.

Comment: Hi @TJ yes I am aware of that. This is only a test we are doing. The next step is to move to a Compose - (the way it should be). But for now I am doing `redis-server` before `exec "$@"` in your entrypoint.sh. It is not working. Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
docker run --build-arg REMOTE_HOST=123456  ....
```

Then your docker file should have the following line to retrieve the environment variable.

```
ARG REMOTE_HOST
ENV REMOTE_HOST=$REMOTE_HOST
```

And you should be able to print it using a php echo like the following:

```
 echo 'xdebug.remote_host='.getenv('REMOTE_HOST');
```

However if you just want to pass a host to the container you should be using the *--add-host* argument when running "docker run". Something like the following:

```
docker run --add-host=remote_host:10.180.0.1 ....
```

Comment: Hi kim, this is what I am gettiing, `xdebug.remote_host=.[REMOTE_HOST]`.

Comment: Hi @zwitterion , I have updated the answer, hope this new approach will help