# How to run 2 services during 'docker run'?

Tags: docker, service

I have a Dockerfile that creates an image with Apache/php and redis inside.
I am aware that it should be splitted in 2 containers. But I whant to know if it is possible to start apache and redis during the run process.

For now I could run in two different ways:

1. docker run --rm -p 80:80  -p 6379:6379 -v $MY_FULLPATH:/var/www/html -e REMOTE_HOST=$REMOTE_HOST  my_img  redis-server
2. docker run --rm -p 80:80  -p 6379:6379 -v $MV_FULLPATH:/var/www/html -e REMOTE_HOST=$REMOTE_HOST  my_img  apache2-foreground

If I run using the first method I must open the terminal to manually start apache.
If I run using the second one I must start REDIS manually.

By the documentation : ["If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect."](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) I know that only "redis-server" will be working at the start.

So Is there a way to set booth automatically? .

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache

## Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y figlet

RUN figlet MV_Docker_Build

## UTILITIES
RUN figlet vim
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN figlet wget
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN figlet CURL
RUN apt-get install -y curl



## APACHE2  basic installation
RUN figlet APACHE2
RUN apachectl -M
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apachectl -M


## ====================================================================== > PHP modules

## Note: when installing from php5 for some modules we need to copy from php5/mods-available to local/etc/php/conf.d and create a simbolic link
RUN figlet PHP_MODULES
RUN php -m

RUN apt-get install -y php5-common

RUN apt-get install -y php-calendar
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/calendar.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/calendar.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/calendar.so

#RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar 

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mhash
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mhash.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mhash.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mhash.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-intl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mysql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysql.so

RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gd
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gd.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-vtkgdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/vtkgdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/vtkgdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/vtkgdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-ldap
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ldap.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xsl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xsl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-tidy
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/tidy.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/tidy.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/tidy.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xmlrpc
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xmlrpc.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xmlrpc.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-pgsql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pgsql.so


RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/readline.so

#RUN apt-get install -y php5-snmp
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/snmp.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/snmp.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/snmp.so

RUN figlet PHP_MODULES
RUN php -m


## ====================================================================== > End of PHP modules




## ====================================================================== > REDIS
RUN figlet REDIS
RUN apt-get install -y telnet redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server

## ====================================================================== > NPM
RUN figlet NPM
RUN apt-get install -y npm

## ====================================================================== > COPYING php.ini
RUN figlet COPYING__php.ini
RUN cp /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN ls -l /usr/local/etc/

## ====================================================================== > XDEBUG
# XDEBUG EXTENSION FOR PHP | DOCUMENTATION => https://xdebug.org/docs/remote 
#
# install xdebug and enable it. This block of code goes through the installion from source and compiling steps found
# on the xdebug website
# https://xdebug.org/docs/install
RUN figlet INSTALLING__XDEBUG
RUN cd /tmp \
    && wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.5.4.tgz \
    && tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.4.tgz \
    && cd xdebug-2.5.4 \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure  \
    && make \
    && cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

RUN figlet INSIDE_no-debug-non-zts-20131226/         
RUN ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/



#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596381/how-to-setup-an-variable-env-inside-dockerfile-to-be-overriden-in-a-docker-conta?noredirect=1#comment82150863_47596381
# ADD xdebug configurations
RUN figlet SETTING__XDEBUG__php.ini
RUN { \
        echo '[xdebug]'; \
        echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000'; \  
        echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'; \
        echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug'; \
        echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_host=$REMOTE_HOST'; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini



RUN figlet XDEGUB__IN__php.ini
RUN cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


## ====================================================================== > COMPOSER

RUN figlet Escape_SUDO
RUN exit

RUN figlet Install__COMPOSER
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

RUN composer


## ====================================================================== > PhpUnit

RUN figlet PhpUnit
RUN curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.6.0.phar -L -o phpunit.phar
RUN chmod +x phpunit.phar
RUN mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit



RUN figlet COPYING_entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN figlet Permission_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]

# EXPOSE - PORTS
RUN figlet EXPOSE_PORTS
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 9000
#CMD ["apache2-foreground","redis-server"]



#ADD run.sh /run.sh
COPY run.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run.sh
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/run.sh"]
```

This is the run.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec apache2-foreground &
exec redis-server &
```

This is entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Check if our environment variable has been passed.
if [ -z "${REMOTE_HOST}" ]
then
  echo "REMOTE_HOST has not been set."
  exit 1
else
  sed -i.bak "s/\$REMOTE_HOST/${REMOTE_HOST}/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
fi

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start more than one process a couple of ways:

- Start them as a service
- Start them trough a cron job (@reboot)
- Start processes in backgound

**UPDATE after your Dockerfile post**

Before I'll try to answer a couple of pointers:

- Every time you enter a RUN command in the Dockerfile it will create a new layer and it makes the image bigger and the build slower.
- This container clearly tries to do too much. A container should do 1 thing and 1 thing good.

Having said that, I think I have a solution :-)

- remove the `run.sh`
- change your entrypoint to this:

`#!/bin/bash
    set -e
    # Check if our environment variable has been passed.
    if [ -z "${REMOTE_HOST}" ]
    then
      echo "REMOTE_HOST has not been set."
      exit 1
    else
      sed -i.bak "s/\$REMOTE_HOST/${REMOTE_HOST}/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    fi
    echo "Starting redis"
    exec redis-server &
    exec "$@"`

- and The end of your Dockerfile to this:

`RUN figlet EXPOSE_PORTS
    EXPOSE 80
    #EXPOSE 6379
    EXPOSE 9000
    CMD ["apache2-foreground"]`

rebuild and have fun :-)

[Screenshot of my running console](https://pasteboard.co/GXLIJwm.png)

Comment: Hi Ivonet, I followed your suggestion but it is not working. I have created a run.sh file. Inside I used `#!/usr/bin/env bash exec apache2-foreground & exec redis-server &` . Inside Dockerfile `ADD run.sh /run.sh ...` your code. And I am running `docker run --rm -p 80:80  -v $MY_FULLPATH:/var/www/html -e REMOTE_HOST=$REMOTE_HOST  my_img apache2-foreground` It only starts apache. What am I missing?

Comment: have you build your image again? I've added some extra lines to the post

Comment: yes I did. In fact I have destroyed it. It starts apache or REDIS, depending in what I call during `docker run ...`.

Comment: leave of the argument at the end

Comment: if I leave of the end argument the container exits just after created. I just check inside the container and this is what I found inside run.sh => `root@48b993e1b824:/var/www/html/App/codedeploy# vi run.sh 

#!/bin/sh
service apache2 restart`. It seems that redis-server is not being saved during the build process

Comment: You have to create this shell script outside of your container and ADD it.. It might be a good idea if you edit your question and provide the complete Dockerfile

Comment: yes... this is what I am doing. I have the file inside the same level as my Dockerfile. I will post my Dockerfile.

Comment: After use COPY I can see `#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec apache2-foreground &
exec redis-server &` But still not working. I must start apache or REDIS manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160968/discussion-between-ivonet-and-zwitterion).